# Default Id generating 00000 in MongoDb

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I have DB Structure as follow .

```
public class University
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public IList<College> Colleges { get; set; }
    }
    public class College
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, An university can have multiple colleges .
I'm adding data is as follow

```
IList<College> lstColleges=new List<College>();

    College clg1=new College(){
        Name="Clg1",
        Code="CLG1001"
    };

    College clg2=new College(){
        Name="Clg2",
        Code="CLG1002"
    };

    lstColleges.Add(clg1);
    lstColleges.Add(clg2);

    University unv=new University(){
        Name="UNIV",
        Code="UN101",
        Colleges=lstColleges
    };
    var collections = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<University>("University");
        collections.Insert(unv);
        var id = student.unv;
```

It is correctly Generating Id for University, but for every college, It's generating 000000.

I want to generate a different default Id for each colleges.

Answer (score 1):

Only top level `_id` are automatically assigned.
Those in an embedded document will need to be manually generated.

You could do this in the ctor:

```
public class College
{
    public  College 
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();        
    }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```